# How can I create a simple sequence diagram on the web?

Tags: webapp-rec

I don't have or want to learn Microsoft Visio or other complicated diagramming software.

Is there a web app to generate simple sequence diagrams?

Comment: https://www.genmymodel.com now supports sequence diagrams.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this is off topic?

Comment: @XiaoPeng-ZenUML.com according to the [help/on-topic], recommendation requests are off-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/)  Very easy to use. Look under "More Shapes" for loads of additional shapes you can add to the toolbar. Has various styles of  connectors to link shapes. Lots of export options including .png .svg and own format.

Comment: I like this answer better than my own because it's more featureful.

Answer (score 27):

[Web Sequence Diagrams](https://www.websequencediagrams.com/) lets you create sequence diagrams using a very simple scripting language.  A simple script might look like this, with its results:

```
participant Client as C
participant Server as S

C->S: GET HTTP/1.0 /index.aspx
activate S
note over S: Generate HTML
S->C: 200 OK
```

> [image: HTTP Request]

Comment: looks like online-graphviz :)

Comment: I always forget about this tool when I need it, which is why I asked and answered my own question. The other answers here are welcome and useful, though.

Comment: PlantUML is like WebSequenceDiagrams but supports additional diagram types. Diagrams may also be inserted inside Google documents.

Answer (score 4):

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io) is a free online diagramming application capable of doing this. Currently you would have to group the two elements of the sequence object to get them to move together, but we'll improve that soon.

Comment: Because I got your answer to "review" under the peer reviewing system of this site and not the above answer.

Comment: @David I can't find any template for sequence diagram at `draw.io`. Is there any or not?

Answer (score 3):

[yUML](http://yuml.me/) is my personal favorite for generating diagrams, even if they're not necessarily UML.

Comment: So glad you posted this, awesome tool!

Answer (score 2):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) -> Drawing

Answer (score 1):

[Cacoo](http://cacoo.com/) allows collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an online sequence drawer, with which you can draw a beautiful sequence diagram, with simple pseudo code.
[seqDia](http://seqDia.appspot.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Lovely Charts](http://www.lovelycharts.com/) is very simple to use and has a web and desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more intuitive program than Visio, [LucidChart](http://www.lucidchart.com) is a good option.  It's a HTML5 application that you can pick up very quickly.

LucidChart has very robust UML tools to create sequence diagrams, state diagrams, activity diagrams, etc.

Comment: @Glorfindel That's really not an appropriate addition in my book.  Please don't add someone's personal info without their permission.

Comment: @jonsca I've answered the question on Meta why I feel these edits were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Found another lightweight online sequence diagram tool: http://www.ckwnc.com/

It is similar to seqDia mentioned before. Transforms script to a diagram.

Comment: Per [FAQ#promotion] please disclose your affiliation with the mentioned site, otherwise this post could be deemed spam and removed as such.

Comment: My apologies. I am not related to this site not in any way. I [googled "online sequence diagram"](https://www.google.ee/search?q=online%20sequence%20diagram) and it popped out as ~30th result. Before that I searched an answer from Stack environment and ended up here. Just found a lightweight tool that I wanted to share.